# Word Problem: Dimensions of the corral

Tags: calculus, area, word-problem

Question: A two-pen corral is to be built. The outline off the corral forms two identical adjoining rectangles, as shown in the diagram below. If there is $120$m of fencing available and the fence width cannot be less than $6$m, what dimensions of the corral will maximize the enclosed area?

[image]

*I got really confused on this question as I don't know how to solve it. I am confused on what the question is asking me and what formula to use. I'd appreciate if anyone can help me solve this question.

Comment: Well, I'd start by drawing a picture.  Then label the relevant dimensions in your picture, express the constraint that you were given and then optimize the area subject to the constraint(s).  Note:  It's not at all clear to me from the question which dimension in the width, and that distinction might matter.

Comment: post edit:  happily the picture indicates which dimension is the width, and thereby removes the potential ambiguity.

Comment: You can do this without calculus.  $L = \frac {(120 - 3W)}{2}, A = LW  = 60 W - \frac 32 W^2.$  Find the vertex of the parabola.

Answer (score 0):

Define $x$ as the length of one pen of the corral and $y$ the width of the corral. Then you know that:

$$4x+3y = k,  \:\: y \geq 6  , \:\: k \leq 120$$

And you want to find $\max\{f(x)=Area(corral)=2xy\}$ , so you can rewrite it as $\max\{f(x) =Area(corral)=\frac{2x(k-4x)}{3}\}$, then you impose the condition $f'(x) = 0$ to find the maximum which results in :

$$\frac{2k}{3}-\frac{16}{3}x=0 \iff x= \frac{k}{8} $$

So $y=\frac{k}{6}$ . Then , $\max\{f(x)\} = k^2/24$ , so the choice $k=120$ is the best one, then: $$x=15,\:y=20$$

I wanted to be formal defining $k \leq 120$ instead of putting just $120$ from the start but it's obvious that $120$ is the right one because the area of the corral is rectangular, so the more you increment the width or the length the more you cover area.